# Passing down a prop who's value is calculated when passed down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to return a Component with a `isMyOffer` prop.

```
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {Object.keys(offers).map(key => (
        <Offer
        key={key}
        index={key}
        details={offers[key]}
        account={this.props.account}
        isMyOffer={this.props.checkIfMyOffer(key, this.props.account.myOffers)}
        addToMyOffers={this.props.addToMyOffers}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

My function `checkIfMyOffer()` should return true on the first **Offer** created and false for the others but it is returning false for all of them.

```
checkIfMyOffer = (offerKey, myOffers) => {
    if(myOffers){
        Object.keys(myOffers).forEach(key => {
            if(offerKey === myOffers[key]) {
                console.log("return " + offerKey)
                return true
            }
        })
    }
    return false
};
```

The `console.log` shows that I am entering the condition loop but my Offer component still has *false* as its isMyOffer value.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can't `return` from within a `forEach()` I'm pretty sure

Comment: Thats true. I switched it to `.map` but still getting the same mistake.

Comment: You should check the recent release for context API in React for passing props globally. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(myOffers) {
  if(Object.values(myOffers).find(x => x === offerKey)) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

This approach uses `Array.prototype.find()` to see if the key is in the `Object.values()` array.

Alternately can use `.includes()` as OP stated:

```
if(myOffers) {
  if(Object.values(myOffers).includes(offerKey)) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

Comment: Problem here is that **offerkey** is not equal to a **myOffer** key but rather to a value of that **myOffer** key. `myOffer[key]`

Comment: I changed answer to `Object.values()`

Comment: Tried your modified version. Getting the following error: `offer123 is not a function` where offer123 is the offerKey. (and also one of the myOffers key value)

Comment: I used your answer and replaced `.find()` with `.includes()`. You can modify it in your answer. Thank your for your help.

Comment: I see my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `checkIfMyOffer` as follows:

```
checkIfMyOffer = (offerKey, myOffers) => {
    return myOffers && Object.keys(myOffers).some(key => myOffers[key] === offerKey);
```

Or you don't event need it and can just update your React.Component:

```
<Offer
   key={key}
   index={key}
   details={offers[key]}
   account={this.props.account}
   sMyOffer={myOffers && Object.keys(myOffers).some(offerKey => myOffers[offerKey] === key)}
   addToMyOffers={this.props.addToMyOffers}
/>
```

Comment: It checks out. I'll probably stick with the separate function since I plan on using it elsewhere but good explanation thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a separate function is a good idea. I reckon the core idea is when you want to get a `boolean` value out of an array/object, there are couple of use functions that ES6 provides: `some`, `every`, `find` and you can return them directly instead of using a if/else condition then return `true/false`

Comment: Yeah I did not know about those. I'll definitely look them up. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I see here:

1- Your `checkIfMyOffer` function will always return `false` reason for that is you are not returning  anything from within your if statement. You are just iterating through an array with the `forEach`

2- I see you are attempting to use a return on a forEach. ForEach does not return a value, it simply iterates through an array and does whatever in each element. [See more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

If you want to return a new array element into a new array, I'd recommend using `.map`. This will return an array of true or false

3- For you to return the results of the `.map` you need to actually return the whole operation. If you did it just by replacing `forEach` for `.map` it would just continue on until it hits your `return false` at the end of your function.

In your case, you want to return true when a certain element is in your object, so your code should look like this:

```
checkIfMyOffer = (offerKey, myOffers) => {
    if(myOffers){
        return Object.keys(myOffers).map(key => {
        if(offerKey === myOffers[key]) {
            console.log("return " + offerKey)
            return true
        }
    })
    }
    return false
};
```

Not sure if this was what you were looking for. But hopefully it helps.

Edit: Clearly the array isn't what you were looking for. My bad for misunderstanding! If you only want to know if your `offerKey` is in `myOffers` you can use the `in` operator ([see more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)). Basically it returns true if a key is found in your object and false otherwise. So in this casem we want to update the `checkIfMyOffer` as follows:

```
checkIfMyOffer = (offerKey, myOffers) => {
    if(myOffers){
        return offerKey in myOffers
    }
    return false
};
```

Comment: I'm getting an array as the **isMyOffer** value since it is returning Object.keys()... Is that return on purpose?

Comment: Ohh ok, so you only want to boolean value? Basically true or false if the offer is in your `myOffers` object?

Comment: Yes exactly. If offerKey matches the value of one of the myOffers keys.

Comment: That works better but here **offerKey** needs to be compared to **myOffers[key]** values and not the keys themselves. This answer would work well if the comparison was with the keys though.